# How to make the check box checked by default when using check_box_tag?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

```
= form_tag movies_path, :id => 'ratings_form', :method => :get do

  Include:

  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    - is_checked = (!@selected_ratings.nil? && @selected_ratings.include?(rating))
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", is_checked, is_checked, {:id => "ratings_#{rating}"}
    = submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => 'ratings_submit'
```

Comment: Indentation is important in HAML code, please ensure that the indentation in your post matches that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Ref :- [`check_box_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002246)

Change

```
check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", is_checked, is_checked, {:id => "ratings_#{rating}"}
```

to

```
check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", is_checked, true, {:id => "ratings_#{rating}"}
```

Comment: But those checkboxes should automatically be checked when i click the refresh button (only for those ratings on the screen).. but instead of that after pressing refresh but all the checkboxes are getting checked instead of selected ratings....